# Prevent homepage showing up for few seconds when directly entered a internal route url in browser

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a navbar that is working fine with nuxt-link. But when I try to access say /about it is showing up homepage for few seconds before loading the actual page.
ie.directly entering the about route like https://www.mywebsite.com/about

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: I have made a static site using nuxt js.It's working fine.When I try to navigate between pages via navbar it works as expected.But when I try to navigate to a particular page by directly entering the url lets say /contact as https://www.mywebsite.com/contact directly on browser it shows homepage for few seconds on load and then displays the contact page.It looks annoying on slow networks.

Comment: http://facilio.tv/platform-overview try navigating this link.It shows index page initially.

Comment: It seems like you are using a [configuration for SPA](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/netlify-deployment/#for-site-generated-in-spa-mode) on your server. So you are redirecting to `index.html` on every route. But you don't need to do that, since you have statically generated site, those pages exist and you can serve them directly. I'm not sure though, don't have an experience with static generated deployment and I haven't seen your routing config.